# How to get String back from hash value in Spacy Library?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am working in Natural Language Processing with the spaCy library. How can I get back a string value from a hash?

Here is my code with details in python with the spaCy library

Note- this question is mainly related with spaCy library and not python.

```
# import spacy package for english language
from spacy.lang.en import English

# initialize nlp with English
nlp = English()

# get hash from string
cat_hash = nlp.vocab.strings["cat"]
print(cat_hash)

# Look up the cat_hash to get the string
cat_string = nlp.vocab.strings[cat_hash]
print(cat_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting. `nlp.vocab.strings` does not contain all the words of English language.
`len(nlp.vocab.strings)` reveals that there are only 1009 words there - mainly functions words: pronouns, aux verbs etc. You can see them all with

```
for s in nlp.vocab.strings:
     print(s)
```

Now, you can still ask for hash value with `nlp.vocab.strings["cat"]` but it doesn't add "cat" to strings, just returns its hash. That's why the lookup   `nlp.vocab.strings[cat_hash]` doesn't work - "cat" is not there and neither is its hash.

In general, hash is not unique and therefore not reversable. Now, you can add word to StringStore (it sill gets the same hash as hash ins independent of the StringStore) and then you will be able to look it up

```
>>> cat_hash = nlp.vocab.strings.add("cat")
>>> cat_hash
5439657043933447811
>>> nlp.vocab.strings[5439657043933447811]
'cat'
```

P.S. Perhaps, what you want to use is `nlp.vocab` and not `nlp.vocab.strings`. `nlp.vocab` does create new entry if the string is absent from dictionary and it can be used with hash too. However, it doesn't return a hash but a `Lexeme` which has `text` and `orth` properties

```
>>> dog=nlp.vocab["dog"]
>>> dog.text
'dog'
>>> dog.orth
7562983679033046312
>>> nlp.vocab[7562983679033046312].text
'dog'
>>>
```